# No android.content.SyncAdapter meta-data

Tags: android, synchronization, adapter, kotlin, authenticator

I'm trying to implement the sync-adapter for my app and i'm encountering this issue:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.content.SyncAdapter
>   meta-data

Due to this ( i hope), my sync adapter is not calling onPerformSync(). I know that this question was previously asked but the answers don't help in my case. I have to mention that i'm using a StubContentProvider as in the google example and here are some of the configuration files :

Manifest:

```
 <service android:name=".sync.AuthenticatorService">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name=".sync.StubContentProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.sync.StubContentProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:syncable="true" />

    <!-- Sync Adapter -->
    <service
        android:name=".sync.SyncDataService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

syncadapter.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/account_authorities"
    android:accountType="one.random.net"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:userVisible="true" />
```

authenticator.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="one.random.net"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

SyncSupport.kt:

```
fun setupSyncAdapter(context: Context) {
        // Create the account type and default account
        val accountName = context.getString(R.string.account_name)
        val accountType = ACCOUNT_TYPE
        val newAccount = Account(accountName, accountType)
        Log.d("Sync", "Account is $newAccount")
        // Get an instance of the account manager
        val accountManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE) as AccountManager
        Log.d("Sync", "Account manager")
        // Add the account and account type, no password or user data
        // If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
        Log.d("Sync", "Account manager size ${accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType).size}")
      /*  ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, AUTHORITY, true)
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(newAccount, AUTHORITY, 1)*/

        try {
            if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null)) {
                //  If you don't set android:syncable="true" in your <provider> element in the
                // manifest, then call context.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1) here
                Log.d("Sync", "Sync Account added")
            } else {
                // The account exists or some other error occurred. Log this, report it,
                // or handle it internally.
                Log.d("Sync", "Sync Account not added or error")
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.e("SyncSupport", e.message, e)
            return
        }

        periodicSync(context)

    }

    /**
     * Expedite a sync request, this will run even if there is sync queued up.
     *
     * **Remember this does IO, and should be threaded**

     * @param context
     */
    fun requestSyncNow(context: Context) {
        val account = getAccount(context) ?: return

        // Pass the settings flags by inserting them in a bundle
        val settingsBundle = Bundle()
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true)
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true)
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(KEY_SYNC, true)
        // Request the sync for the default account, authority, and manual sync settings
      /*  ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true)
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)*/
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle)
    }

    /**
     * Requests a sync, at the next opportunity.
     *
     *
     * **This does IO, remember to call it off the UI thread.**

     * @param context
     */
    fun requestSync(context: Context) {
        val account = getAccount(context) ?: return

        val settingsBundle = Bundle()
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(KEY_SYNC, true)
        /*
     * Signal the framework to run your sync adapter. Assume that
     * app initialization has already created the account.
     */
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true)
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle)

    }

    fun periodicSync(context: Context) {
        val account = getAccount(context) ?: return
        Log.d("Sync", "Periodic sync triggered")
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true)
    //    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
        // We run the Sync Adapter every 12 hours normally or every 5 min's on dev to test.
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        val pollPeriod = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(5L) else TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12L)
        val settingsBundle = Bundle()

        settingsBundle.putBoolean(KEY_SYNC, true)

        val b = SyncRequest.Builder().syncPeriodic(pollPeriod, pollPeriod)
        b.setSyncAdapter(account, AUTHORITY)
        b.setExtras(settingsBundle)
        ContentResolver.requestSync(b.build())

        //Timber.i("Sync: PeriodicSync: %ss", pollPeriod.toString())
    }

    fun getAccount(context: Context): Account? {
        val accountManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE) as AccountManager
        val accountsByType = accountManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE)
        for (account in accountsByType) return account
        return null
    }
```

From what i've checked multiple times the strings are OK but for some reason i'm still getting this error.